# C# 0-1 Knapsack Problem with known sum and number of zeros in set

Tags: c#, algorithm, knapsack-problem

I have a 5x5 table of values from 0 to 3 inclusive with all values unknown.  I know both the sum of the values and the number of zeros for each row and column.  How would I go about solving this 0-1 knapsack problem using C# and retrieving the possible solutions that satisfy the known sums and number of zeros?  The tables will always be five rows and five columns, so it's not quite a traditional knapsack.

For example, say we input:

```
Row[0]: Sum=4, Zeros=1
   [1]: Sum=5, Zeros=1
   [2]: Sum=4, Zeros=2
   [3]: Sum=8, Zeros=0
   [4]: Sum=3, Zeros=2

Col[0]: Sum=5, Zeros=1
   [1]: Sum=3, Zeros=2
   [2]: Sum=4, Zeros=2
   [3]: Sum=5, Zeros=1
   [4]: Sum=7, Zeros=0
```

We would get this as a possible solution:

```
[[ 0 1 1 1 1 ]
 [ 1 0 2 1 1 ]
 [ 2 1 0 0 1 ]
 [ 1 1 1 2 3 ]
 [ 1 0 0 1 1 ]]
```

What type of algorithm should I employ in this rather strange situation?  Would I also have to write a class just to enumerate the permutations?

**Edit for clarification:** the problem isn't that I can't enumerate the possibilities; it's that I have no clue how to go about efficiently determining the permutations adding to an arbitrary sum while containing the specified number of zeros and a maximum of 5 items.

Comment: What code did you write until now to solve this problem? Can you post that?

Comment: and maybe add the "homework" tag (if it isn't homework I'd really like to know for what it is).

Comment: How is this related to knapsack?

Comment: Technically you could simply enumerate all the solutions. There are 2^50 possible tables, you then check your constraints.

Comment: @Valmond: Not quite homework, just an exercise to ease my frustration at a puzzle game.

Comment: @CKoenig I believe that is NP you're referring to. Knapsack is a problem solved by dynamic programming.

Comment: What quasiverse said. I also believe this is not knapsack, but rather an NP (-hard?) problem. A bruteforce should quickly get a solution though.

Comment: yes sorry - I thought on trapdoor ... sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here there is the code. If you need any comment feel free to ask:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication15
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RowOrCol[] rows = new RowOrCol[] { 
                new RowOrCol(4, 1),
                new RowOrCol(5, 1),
                new RowOrCol(4, 2),
                new RowOrCol(8, 0),
                new RowOrCol(3, 2),
            };

            RowOrCol[] cols = new RowOrCol[] { 
                new RowOrCol(5, 1),
                new RowOrCol(3, 2),
                new RowOrCol(4, 2),
                new RowOrCol(5, 1),
                new RowOrCol(7, 0),
            };

            int[,] table = new int[5, 5];

            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            int solutions = Do(table, rows, cols, 0, 0);

            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Found {0} solutions in {1}ms", solutions, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static int Do(int[,] table, RowOrCol[] rows, RowOrCol[] cols, int row, int col)
        {
            int solutions = 0;

            int oldValueRowSum = rows[row].Sum;
            int oldValueRowZero = rows[row].Zeros;
            int oldValueColSum = cols[col].Sum;
            int oldValueColZero = cols[col].Zeros;

            int nextCol = col + 1;
            int nextRow;
            bool last = false;

            if (nextCol == cols.Length)
            {
                nextCol = 0;

                nextRow = row + 1;

                if (nextRow == rows.Length)
                {
                    last = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                nextRow = row;
            }

            int i;

            for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                table[row, col] = i;

                if (i == 0)
                {
                    rows[row].Zeros--;
                    cols[col].Zeros--;

                    if (rows[row].Zeros < 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (cols[col].Zeros < 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        rows[row].Zeros++;
                        cols[col].Zeros++;
                    }

                    rows[row].Sum--;
                    cols[col].Sum--;

                    if (rows[row].Sum < 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (cols[col].Sum < 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (col == cols.Length - 1)
                {
                    if (rows[row].Sum != 0 || rows[row].Zeros != 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                if (row == rows.Length - 1)
                {
                    if (cols[col].Sum != 0 || cols[col].Zeros != 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                if (!last)
                {
                    solutions += Do(table, rows, cols, nextRow, nextCol);
                }
                else 
                {
                    solutions++;

                    Console.WriteLine("Found solution:");

                    var sums = new int[cols.Length];
                    var zeross = new int[cols.Length];

                    for (int j = 0; j < rows.Length; j++)
                    {
                        int sum = 0;
                        int zeros = 0;

                        for (int k = 0; k < cols.Length; k++)
                        {
                            Console.Write("{0,2} ", table[j, k]);

                            if (table[j, k] == 0)
                            {
                                zeros++;
                                zeross[k]++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sum += table[j, k];
                                sums[k] += table[j, k];
                            }
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("| Sum {0,2} | Zeros {1}", sum, zeros);

                        Debug.Assert(sum == rows[j].OriginalSum);
                        Debug.Assert(zeros == rows[j].OriginalZeros);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("---------------");

                    for (int j = 0; j < cols.Length; j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("{0,2} ", sums[j]);
                        Debug.Assert(sums[j] == cols[j].OriginalSum);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine();

                    for (int j = 0; j < cols.Length; j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("{0,2} ", zeross[j]);
                        Debug.Assert(zeross[j] == cols[j].OriginalZeros);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }

            // The for cycle was broken at 0. We have to "readjust" the zeros.
            if (i == 0)
            {
                rows[row].Zeros++;
                cols[col].Zeros++;
            }

            // The for cycle exited "normally". i is too much big because the true last cycle was at 3.
            if (i == 4)
            {
                i = 3;
            }

            // We readjust the sums.
            rows[row].Sum += i;
            cols[col].Sum += i;

            Debug.Assert(oldValueRowSum == rows[row].Sum);
            Debug.Assert(oldValueRowZero == rows[row].Zeros);
            Debug.Assert(oldValueColSum == cols[col].Sum);
            Debug.Assert(oldValueColZero == cols[col].Zeros);

            return solutions;
        }
    }

    public class RowOrCol
    {
        public readonly int OriginalSum;
        public readonly int OriginalZeros;

        public int Sum;
        public int Zeros;

        public RowOrCol(int sum, int zeros)
        {
            this.Sum = this.OriginalSum = sum;
            this.Zeros = this.OriginalZeros = zeros;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Marked as answer and +1.  Thanks for the help!  It was the recursion that got me.

Comment: @hydroiodic Probably it can be done without recursion or stacks, you know?

Answer (score 1):

How fast does it have to be? I just tested a naive "try pretty much anything" with some early aborts but less than would be possible, and it was pretty fast (less than a millisecond). It gave the solution:

```
[[ 0 1 1 1 1 ]
 [ 1 0 1 1 2 ]
 [ 1 0 0 1 2 ]
 [ 2 1 2 2 1 ]
 [ 1 1 0 0 1 ]]
```

If that's an acceptable solution to you, I can post the code (or just discuss it, it's quite verbose but the underlying idea is trivial)

edit: it is also trivially extendable to enumerating all solutions. It found 400 of them in 15 milliseconds, and claims that there are no more than that. Is that correct?

---

What I did, was start at 0,0 and try all values I could fill in at that place (0 though min(3, rowsum[0])), fill it it (subtracting it from rowsum[y] and colsum[x] and subtracting one from rowzero[y] and colzero[x] if the value was zero), then recursively do this for 0,1; 0,2; 0,3; then at 0,4 I have a special case where I just fill in the remaining rowsum if it is non-negative (otherwise, abort the current try - ie go up in the recursion tree), and something similar for when y=4. In the mean time, I abort when any rowsum colsum colzero or rowzero becomes negative.

The current board is a solution if and only if all remaining rowsums columnsums colzero's and rowzero's are zero. So I just test for that, and add it to the solutions if it is one. It won't have any negative entries by construction.

Comment: Alright, added an explanation of what I did. Do you want the code as well?

Comment: +1.  That got me on my feet again.  Thanks!  I was doing a bunch of ugly for loops within for loops within foreach loops before I saw that answer.

Comment: I just tried restricting the choices for each entry more (with a lookup table that takes the number of zero's and the sum) and while that threw away about half the choices it ended up being slower. The problem instance is really too small for such tricks to pay off :(